# Laravel Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed,some problem with my category_id foreign key,

Tags: laravel

Laravel Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed,some problem with my category_id foreign key

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel Migration Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32669880/laravel-migration-foreign-key-constraint-is-incorrectly-formed)

Comment: can you show us your table and model.?

Answer (score 0):

```
  $table->unsignedBigInteger('anynameyouwant_id');
  $table->foreign('anynameyouwant_id')->references('id')->on('which table you want to refer');
```

this is the basic concept of the foreign key in laravel.
.