# Foreign key constraint, even after using bigIncrements and unsignedBigInteger

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

so in my Tasks migration table I'm trying to reference a foriegn key constraint

Illuminate\Database\QueryException  : SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint (SQL: alter table `tasks` add constraint `tasks_article_id_foreign` foreign key (`article_id`) references `articles` (`id`) on delete cascade)

I've followed up on google regarding the error, it says to use unsignedBigInteger for bigIncrements reference. I did that but still I get  this error:

I followed this link: [Laravel Migration Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32669880/laravel-migration-foreign-key-constraint-is-incorrectly-formed)

Can you guys point me in the right direction?

```
    {
        Schema::create('tasks', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('title');
            $table->string('task_url');
            $table->string('task_unique_id');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id')->default(1);
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('article_id')->nullable();
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('project_id')->nullable();
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('category_id')->nullable();
            $table->boolean('is_completed')->default(0);
            $table->timestamps();


            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->foreign('article_id')->references('id')->on('articles')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->foreign('project_id')->references('id')->on('projects')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->foreign('category_id')->references('id')->on('categories')->onDelete('cascade');

        });
    }
```

Comment: The articles table exists?

Comment: Not before tasks is  migrated. As in Article, Project, Category they all come after Task table.

Comment: You can't reference to a table wich not exist. Run this migration after all referenced tales was created

Comment: As in change timestamps of migration file? Im confused how do I run a specific migration before  Tasks table?

Comment: Yes you can change the timestamp in the migration filename to change the migrations order. Note maybe you'll have to run `composer dump-autoload` after change migeations filenames

Comment: Thanks that worked, i changed the  month number.

Answer (score 0):

You can disable the foreign key checks before the create method and re enable afterwards.

```
{
    Schema::disableForeignKeyConstraints();
    Schema::create('tasks', function (Blueprint $table) {
        ....
    });
    Schema::enableForeignKeyConstraints();
}
```

Comment: Changing the migration file name, doing composer dump-autoload worked. Thanks  anyways for your help  :)