# Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed in MySQL: Laravel migration

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, database-migration

My migrations are

```
Schema::create('user_details', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->Increments('id')->unique();
    $table->text('detail');
    $table->text('value');
    $table->integer('user_id');
    $table->timestamps();

    $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
});
```

and

```
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->Increments('id')->unique();
    $table->integer('user_detail_id');
    $table->integer('user_setting_id');
    $table->integer('company_id');
    $table->mediumText('role');
    $table->mediumText('email')->unique();
    $table->mediumText('password');
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

When I try to migrate, I'm getting this error message:

> errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed" (SQL: alter
>   table `user_details` add constraint `user_details_user_id_foreign`
>   fore ign key (`user_id`) references `users` (`id`))

Why is this happening?

Comment: the field types have to match exactly ... `increments` creates an unsigned integer, you are creating just an integer field (user_id), needs to also be unsigned ... and assuming `users` migration is before `user_details`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel migration: "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed" (errno 150)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32669880/laravel-migration-foreign-key-constraint-is-incorrectly-formed-errno-150)

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the `InnoDB` storage engine for your tables. You can either do it in schema builder: `$table->engine = 'InnoDB';` or in `config/database.php` file (`connections => mysql => engine`): change `'engine' => null,` to `'engine' => 'InnoDB',`.

Second, primary keys which are defined like `$table->increments('id');` are auto-incrementing **UNSIGNED INTEGER**. And your foreign keys should be unsigned integer. Read more about [creating columns](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/migrations#creating-columns).

```
Schema::create('user_details', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->engine = 'InnoDB';

    $table->increments('id');
    $table->text('detail');
    $table->text('value');
    $table->unsignedInteger('user_id');
    $table->timestamps();

    $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
});
```

```
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->engine = 'InnoDB';

    $table->increments('id');
    $table->integer('user_detail_id');
    $table->integer('user_setting_id');
    $table->integer('company_id');
    $table->mediumText('role');
    $table->mediumText('email')->unique();
    $table->mediumText('password');
    $table->timestamps();
});
```