# Laravel migration error in foresign key 150

Tags: laravel

I started working on small project using Laravel latest version, i try to make a foreign key between two table ( Buildings and Appartmens ) but i get an error message  contain :

```
("SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table `project`.`apartments` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")")
```

this is my `buildings` table schema :

```
Schema::create('buildings', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->string('address');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

this is my `apartments` table schema :

```
Schema::create('apartments', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->string('number');
        $table->integer('monthly_price');
        $table->integer('rooms');
        $table->integer('bath_room');
        $table->string('description');
        // Foreign Key 
        $table->foreignId('building_id')->constrained('buildings');
        // Record Times
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel migration: "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed" (errno 150)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32669880/laravel-migration-foreign-key-constraint-is-incorrectly-formed-errno-150)

Comment: @jewishmoses same problem :(

Comment: In which order are these migrations running? the buildings migration has to run before the apartments migration.

Comment: @Remul apartments runs first i think, how can i flip the order ?

Comment: You could rename them and change the date, or delete the apartments migration and create a new one.

Comment: @Remul, its okey i have changed the name of the migration like that i have changed the order thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your `apartments` migration runs before your `buildings` migration, so no foreign key can be created because the buildings table has not yet been created.

To fix this you can change the date that prefixes the migration, for example:

```
2020_08_03_140214_create_apartments_table

2020_08_03_140387_create_buildings_table
```

to:

```
2020_08_03_140387_create_buildings_table

2020_08_03_140388_create_apartments_table
```

Don't forget to run a `composer dump-autoload` afterwards in order to update the class maps as well.