# laravel migration to add foreign key

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, migrate

I'm trying to add foreign key in my table exam:

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('exams', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->BigInteger('student_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
            $table->BigInteger('subject_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
            $table->integer('mark');
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->foreign('student_id')
            ->references('id')
            ->on('students');
            $table->foreign('subject_id')
            ->references('id')
            ->on('subjects');
        });
    }
```

Student's table:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('students', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->string('fname');
        $table->string('mname');
        $table->string('lname');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

Subject's table:

```
Schema::create('subjects', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('title');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

I have searched a lot and try it with `unsignedBigInteger` or `$table->bigInteger('student_id')->unsigned()->nullable();` and try this:

[Laravel migration: "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed" (errno 150)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32669880/laravel-migration-foreign-key-constraint-is-incorrectly-formed-errno-150)

But this error is still happening when I use `php artisan migrate`
What can i do?

> Illuminate\Database\QueryException
>
> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table
> `salamstu`.`exams` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly
> formed") (SQL: alter table `exams` add constraint
> `exams_student_id_foreign` foreign key (`student_id`) references
> `students` (`id`) on delete cascade)
>
> at
> C:\Users\User\Documents\laravel\SalamStu\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:716
> 712▕         // If an exception occurs when attempting to run a query,  we'll format the error
> 713▕         // message to include the bindings with SQL, which will make this exception a
> 714▕         // lot more helpful to the developer instead of just the database's errors.
> 715▕         catch (Exception $e) {   ➜ 716▕             throw new QueryException(
> 717▕                 $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
> 718▕             );
> 719▕         }
> 720▕     }
>
> 1
> C:\Users\User\Documents\laravel\SalamStu\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:501
> PDOException::("SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table `salamstu`.`exams` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is
> incorrectly formed")")
>
> 2
> C:\Users\User\Documents\laravel\SalamStu\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:501
> PDOStatement::execute()

Comment: Did you run the `students` migration first?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$table->bigIncrements('id');` = `Auto-incrementing UNSIGNED BIGINT (primary key)` equivalent column.

`$table->increments('id');` = `Auto-incrementing UNSIGNED INTEGER (primary key)` equivalent column.

`INT[(M)] [UNSIGNED] [ZEROFILL]`

A normal-size integer. The signed range is `-2147483648` to `2147483647`. The `unsigned` range is `0` to `4294967295`.

`BIGINT[(M)] [UNSIGNED] [ZEROFILL]`

A large integer. The `signed` range is `-9223372036854775808` to `9223372036854775807`. The unsigned range is `0` to `18446744073709551615`.

For `$table->increments('id');`, use this:

```php
$table->unsignedInteger('student_id')->nullable();
$table->foreign('student_id')->references('id')->on('students');
```

For `$table->bigIncrements('id');`, use this:

```php
$table->unsignedBigInteger('student_id')->nullable();
$table->foreign('student_id')->references('id')->on('students');
```