# Laravel mysql error relational databases?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Syntax error or access violation: 1072 Key column 'collection_id' doesn't exist in table (SQL: alter table `products` add constraint `products_collection_id_foreign` foreign key (`collection_id`) references `collections` (`id`) on delete cascade)

So im having this issue trying to relation products with collections with a collection_id.

This is my collection migration

```
    class CreateCollectionsTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('collections', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('author');
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('collections');
    }
}
```

This is my product migration

```
class CreateProductsTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('products', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->string('name');
            $table->integer('price');
            $table->string('src');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('collection_id');
            $table->foreign('collection_id')->references('id')->on('collections')->onDelete("cascade");
            $table->integer('amount');
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('products');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it the following way.

```
$table->unsignedBigInteger('collection_id');
$table->foreign('collection_id')->references('id')->on('collections')->onDelete("cascade");
```

And one more thing run the following command :

```
php artisan migrate:fresh
```

or

```
 php artisan migrate:refresh
```

hope your problem will be resolved.or
can follow the following URL
[Laravel migration: "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed" (errno 150)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32669880/laravel-migration-foreign-key-constraint-is-incorrectly-formed-errno-150)

Answer (score 1):

are your migrations running correctly you might also check the migrations sequence on creating the table if the collection is being created first before the products, if products are created before collection it throws this error because the collection is not yet created, also there's a shortcut for defining foreign keys which is

```
$table->foreignId('collection_id')->constrained()->cascadeOnDelete();
```